# Value of the integral $\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\delta(k_2\cdot e^{i\theta}+k_3\cdot e^{j\phi} +z )d\theta d\phi$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, dirac-delta

I would like to compute the following integral, which arises from some physics problems, where $k_2$, $k_3$ are real, $z$ is in general complex,
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\delta(k_2\cdot e^{i\theta}+k_3\cdot e^{j\phi} +z )d\theta d\phi
$$
First integrate over $\theta$,

$$
\int_0^{2\pi} \delta(k_2\cdot e^{i\theta}+ \gamma)d\theta,\qquad \gamma=k_3\cdot e^{j\phi} + z
$$

Then make the change of variables,

$$
\oint_c \delta(k_2\cdot x+ \gamma)\cdot\frac{1}{ix} dx
=\oint_c i \frac{k_2}{\gamma}dx = 2\pi i \cdot\frac{k_2}{\gamma}
$$

Plug this into the integral over $\phi$, do the same change of variable,

$$
\int_0^{2\pi} 2i\pi\cdot\frac{k_2}{k_3\cdot e^{j\phi} + z} d\phi=\oint_c 2i\pi\cdot\frac{k_2}{k_3\cdot y + z}\cdot\frac{1}{iy} dy = 2\pi \oint_c \frac{k_2/k_3}{y( y + z/k_3) }dy,
$$

Finally apply the residue theorem,

$$
R(0)=2\pi(k_2/k_3)\lim_{y \to 0} y\cdot \frac{1}{y( y + z/k_3)} = (2\pi i)\cdot 2\pi k_2/z
$$

while if $|-z/k_3|<1$,

$$
R(-z/k_3)=2\pi(k_2/k_3)\lim_{y \to -z/k_3} ( y + z/k_3)\cdot \frac{1}{y( y + z/k_3)}= - (2\pi i)\cdot 2\pi k_2/z
$$

I was wondering if I did something wrong, in this case $z$ has to be pure imaginary to get the final integral real? also, it seems strange because the result does not explicitly depend on $k_3$.

Comment: @Did thanks for you hint!

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/937829/

Answer (score 2):

I am no expert in the ways physicists manipulate Dirac deltas but I believe that, for every suitable functions $u$ and $v$, they consider that
$$
\int \delta(u(t))v(t)\mathrm dt=\sum_t\frac{v(t)}{|u'(t)|},
$$
where the sum is on the finite set of roots $t$ of $u(t)=0$. Thus, for every nonzero $\gamma$,
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \delta(k_2\cdot e^{i\theta}+ \gamma)\mathrm d\theta=\frac1{|\gamma|},$$ provided $|k_2|=|\gamma|$. The integral is zero otherwise. Applying this to each $\gamma=k_3\mathrm e^{i\phi}+z$, one sees that the double integral is $$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\mathbf 1_{|k_3\mathrm e^{i\phi}+z|=|k_2|}\mathrm d\phi}{|k_3\mathrm e^{i\phi}+z|}=\frac1{|k_2|}\int_0^{2\pi}\mathbf 1_{|k_3\mathrm e^{i\phi}+z|=|k_2|}\mathrm d\phi,$$ which is zero in general. The exceptions are when $z=0$ and $|k_3|=|k_2|\ne0$, and then the value is $\dfrac{2\pi}{|k_2|},$ and when $z=|k_3|=|k_2|=0$, and then the value is $4\pi^2$.

Comment: your result depends on neither $k_3$ nor $Z$? seems to me a little bit strange..

Comment: It does very much depend on $z$ since it is zero when $z\ne0$ and may be nonzero when $z=0$. Likewise for $k_3$ (which I called $k_1$, will change that).

Comment: ok, then something may be wrong in my case...

Comment: The fact that this implies $\oint_C \frac{dz}{z} \delta(z-w)=0$ unless $w$ lies on $C$ is rather interesting. It might be illuminating to see what this looks like at the level of nascent delta functions.

Comment: @Semiclassical A direct approach is to choose approximations $\eta_\epsilon$ of $\delta$ such that $\eta_\epsilon(x)=0$ for every $|x|\geqslant\epsilon$. Every $w$ not in $C$ is at positive distance of $C$ hence, for every $w$ not in $C$, $$\oint_C\frac{dz}z\eta_\epsilon(z-w)=0$$ for every $\epsilon$ small enough since $\eta_\epsilon(z-w)=0$ **for every $z$ in $C$**, for every $\epsilon$ small enough.

Comment: That works! The argument I came up with was $\eta_\epsilon(z-w)=\dfrac{\epsilon}{\epsilon^2+(z-w)^2}$; it has poles of opposite residue at $z=w\pm i\epsilon$, so the integral vanishes unless $C$ encloses exactly one pole. In the limit $\epsilon\to 0$ this requires that $C$ include $w$.

Comment: @Semiclassical  so you are numerically integrating a lorenzian? btw, could you see something wrong in my derivation?..

Comment: @lorniper: Not numerically integrating, just 'approximating' the delta-function with the Lorentzian as a way of understanding the integral in the limit $\epsilon\to 0$. As for your derivation, Did's answer looks sensible to me; thus, if yours disagrees with his, I suggest you re-examine your work.